# h2o deeplearning: what is the input variable impact/coefficient?

Tags: h2o, coefficients

I am trying to predict taxi-out times at US airports with a h2o deeplearning model:

```
#Deep learning neural network

  deep<-h2o.deeplearning(
    training_frame = train,
    validation_frame = valid,
    x=predictors,
    y=target,
    #distribution = "gaussian",
    #loss = "Automatic",
    hidden=c(200,200,200),
    epochs = 50,
    #activation="Rectifier",
    stopping_metric="deviance",
    stopping_tolerance=1e-4,      # stops when deviance does not improve by 
                                     >=0.0001 for 5 scoring events
  )

  summary(deep)
```

This is the truncated variable importance list:

Variable Importances:

```
         variable relative_importance scaled_importance percentage
1     Event_1.Fog            1.000000          1.000000   0.024205
2    Event_2.Rain            0.983211          0.983211   0.023799
3      CARRIER.NK            0.946493          0.946493   0.022910
4 Event_1.noevent            0.936131          0.936131   0.022659
5     cos_deptime            0.934558          0.934558   0.022621
```

I understand that the "importance" is calculated as the relative impact of the variable but how do I know if that variable contributes to increase or decrease the taxi-out times? Does h2o shows the coefficient of each variable with a sign?
I have read this doc http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_doc.html but it doesn't explain whether, say, the variable fog or rain increases or decreases taxi-out times and how much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable importance for H2O Deep Learning (or RF or GBM, for that matter) does not have the same interpretation as coefficient magnitude in a GLM (which can be positive or negative), which is what you are describing.  It can be interpreted as "how important is this variable in predicting the outcome", and the measure is relative to the other variables in the model.

As mentioned in the [H2O Deep Learning documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html), we use a technique called the Gedeon method to calculate this measure.  (RF and GBM use a different method).